# Cannot find module 'C:\native\win32\x64\12.13.0\edge_nativeclr'

Tags: typescript, electron

Electron Version: 8
Node: 12.13.0

Hi, I'm getting "Cannot find module 'C:\native\win32\x64\12.13.0\edge_nativeclr' " when I package the application:

// Release
"build": "concurrently "yarn build-main" "yarn build-renderer""
"package": "yarn build && electron-builder build --publish never"

// Dev Mode
"start": "cross-env START_HOT=1 node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckPortInUse.js && cross-env START_HOT=1 yarn start-renderer-dev",

`var libLoader = require('electron-edge-js');`

In dev mode works just fine after adding

```
externals: {
    'electron-edge-js': 'commonjs2 electron-edge-js',
  },
```

into webpack, but when it comes to Release, I get Cannot find module 'C:\native\win32\x64\12.13.0\edge_nativeclr'.

Things that I've tried in order to solve it:

"asar": {
"unpackDir": "node_modules/electron-edge-js/**",
etc...
}

I've also tried to download native and put it in the same location but I did not had any results, I've been searching a little bit on the issues and stack overflow but I did not found any solution.